# Why can't I display an embedded video from a YouTube Live stream?

Tags: api, iframe, youtube, video-streaming, embed

I found a script that lets me use the Youtube API to access a channel, recognise if there is any live stream and give me the id of this specific video that is being broadcasted.

However, when it is embedded on my page as:

```
<iframe width="500" height="600" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/{$this->live_video_id}{$autoplay}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
```

I cannot play it. The video shows up, and when I press "play" it gives me a "Playback error".

I removed the $autoplay part because this was giving me problems and it worked! And then it didn't work. It's so frustrating. I copy-pasted the url only in my address bar

```
www.youtube.com/embed/[Whatever the id is here]
```

and it worked! And then it didn't work. I just cannot understand why it works sometimes and sometimes not.

Everytime I do something it works for 5 seconds and then it breaks and it doesn't want to show it. When I closed the live stream to try with another one. It showed the old (already archived) live stream. Nonsense!

I read somewhere that you need to embed the video from the live stream, but then the whole idea to use an API is futile. Also I tried enabling AdSense because this could also help, but it didn't.

What can I do to get an embedded YouTube live stream video on my website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: 
Since I couldn't figure it out and YouTube tightened their API quota points a lot as of February 2019. I just switched to Twitch API and everything worked from the first try.

Comment: This doesn't solve the question stated by OP, he/she is trying to achieve it using the YouTube API

Comment: Hi Maarten, it is my question (I wanted to 'close' the question by posting an update) and this is the way I solved it. Because it made no sense to use a complex, fairly restricted YouTube API to do the same as the Twitch API. I am posting it so others know that there is an easier way.

Comment: Ah sorry for the confusion, i didn't notice that you answered your own question. I though is was another using suggesting you should switch entirely. I will delete the comment if needed. @michelangelo

Comment: No, no, thanks for noticing. Should I do something more to indicate that the thread is closed?

Comment: Can you mark your own answer as an answer? If this isn't possible you can close your question by choosing `close` next to the edit button.

Comment: @MaartenDev I 'accepted' it, that should do it. Thank you.

Comment: @michelangelo Do you have any details on what those quotas are?

Comment: Hey @Brad not super sure. My problem was that my application just stopped working and threw a 'connection error' because 'probably' the API refused my requests. 

I figured it is because I exceeded the quota. I needed to fetch a video which apparently takes about 10 quota units. So you can check here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas or https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed the `iframe` tag

Correction in code

`<iframe width="500" height="600" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/{$this->live_video_id
{$autoplay}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

[Source](https://webcam.io/support/howto-embed-youtube-live/)